# Bootstrap 2 Menu Size CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using legacy Bootstrap (2.3) and running into a possible CSS issue.

I am creating a popup window to handle a file attachment and I am trying to show a plain navbar with logo on it, removed all of the items from our normal menu.

This looks fine when the window is long but I need about half the size.

When this is scaled down, the container is forcing the navbar down on the page.

This is beibg pushed down because the width of the popup window is smaller than the container.

[image]

[image]

The one above looks fine because the window is larger than the container.
Here is the simple CSS that is causing the issue:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" class="brand"><img src="../resources/images/logo.png" alt="Blueprint" /><div class="brand-text">Blueprint</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't you replicate the mistake in a jsfiddle? There's not much we can do if we can't see the css's involved

Comment: Any other CSS you used??